# SwiftUI: Issue with longer text in TextField on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

When I enter (or paste) text in a `TextField` on macOS and the string requires more space than available in `TextField` I would expect some sort of scrolling behaviour that moves along with the text cursor - like in almost every text field in the world. Instead I only see the beginning of the text and can't see my new input anymore. I cannot even scroll manually. Only if I enlarge the `TextField` and then shrink it again, I am able to scroll through it. See video:

[image: macos text field]

Is this a SwiftUI bug? Any known solutions for this?

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: CNR. Needed MRE to debug.

Comment: I can reproduce this but I have no idea how it can be fixed.

Comment: it's definitely a bug.

Comment: you could try adding `.scaledToFill()`, it does some sort of scrolling, but it may not be what you are looking for. Also you could try `.fixedSize()` and a frame

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Kinda hope Apple will fix this with the release of macOS Ventura (have not tested this with the beta yet though).

Comment: I have not upgraded to MacOS 13 yet, but [the TextField documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield) mentions some new initializers for "Creating a Scrollable Text Field". Hopefully while working on the new API, they also caught and fixed this MacOS bug.

Comment: Maybe try a horizontal scroll view? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems to be a bug. I could reproduce it in 12.0 and 12.5 but Ventura beta release behaves much better.